# Google Maps Markers works only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

What I am trying to do is parse kml file and then show markers on the map at the exact coordinates. User then selects one of the markers and clicks on the button to get a scatter plot with some data points. The problem with the existing code is it only works in Firefox and not Chrome and IE.

I am aware of the option to directly load kml file into maps. Problem with that is that I do not get exactly the same coordinates, at different map zooms, when clicked on the marker.

You can see the page here http://kcotar.org/sqm/sqm_plot.php

Any idea on what it is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in you code (both Chrome and IE10 complained about it):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

`replace` is used two times in file `http://kcotar.org/sqm/js_functions_sqm.js`

Where is element `sqmValueSlider`? It is used in

```
var slider = document.getElementById("sqmValueSlider").value;
```

Similar for element `sqmValueField` used in

```
var svalue = document.getElementById("sqmValueField").value;
```

You have also `/` in the middle of `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" / charset="UTF-8">
```

Most probably it should be at the end like `/>`

**EDIT:** It seems that the following line breaks it:

```
var descr = $(this).find('description').html();
```

With `.text()` instead of `.html()` it continues. I got also markes with description on Chrome and IE10.

**UPDATE:**: `.html()` internally read property `innerHTML`. On Firefox this field is set, on Chrome this propery does not exist. So `.html()` fails because `innerHTML` is undefined.

Comment: Removing unused JS functions in js_functions_sqm.js did not help. If you ask me there is a problem in g_maps.js in function initialize2() in the way how I handle creation of the markers.

Comment: You are right, still getting the same message. Did you check/validate you kml file? There is one marker (NE of Dutovlje) without Date/Time info but most probably that is not the problem. And I am getting one strange message on FF: `Image corrupt or truncated: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png`

Comment: @jegr Updated with possible fix.

Comment: Thank you for help. Now it works. `.html()` was used because description includes html tags, that are stripped with `.text()`.